# ImageButton en libGDX

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

Buen dia, Estoy inentando crear un boton en LibGDX soy nuevo en esto de la creacion de videojuegos y he visto varas formas de implementarlo, el problema es ese mismo IMPLEMENTARLO en mi codigo, nose como hacerlo? este metodo es el que utilizo para navegar entre pantallas pero dando click a la pantalla NO al boton, si alguien me podria ayudar le agradeceria mucho con esto aqui les dejo el codigo de mi clase.

´public class MenuState extends State {

```
//Dimensiones a utilizar para las imagenes de inicio
private static final int WIDTHPLAY = 275;
private static final int HEIGTHPLAY = 200;
private static final int WIDTHPAJARO = 150;
private static final int HEIGTHPAJARO = 150;
private static final int WIDTHPLETRAS = 425;
private static final int HEIGTHLETRAS = 100;

private Stage stage;
private TextButton button;
private TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle;
private BitmapFont font;
private Skin skin;
private TextureAtlas buttonAtlas;

//Declaracion de los assets a utilizar en la pantalla principal
//La palabra Texture es una libreria para agregar texturas en libGDX
private Texture background;
private Texture btninicial;
private Texture imagenPajaro;
private Texture imagenLetras;



public MenuState(GameStateManager gameStateManager) {
    super(gameStateManager);

    //Inicializar las variables de los assets y agregar las imagenes
    background = new Texture("bgprincipal.jpg");
    btninicial = new Texture("play.png");
    imagenPajaro = new Texture("pajaro.png");
    imagenLetras = new Texture("iniciotexto.png");

    }




/*
 * HandleInput evalua todas las entrasa que
 * tendremos es decir cuando estamos interactuando
 * con el
 */


@Override
public void HandleInput() {
    /*
     * Metodo para definir cuando se
     * este tocando la pantalla pantalla
     * principal navege hacia la segunda
     */

     if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
        dispose();
   }

}



/*
 * update ejecuta los metodos que realizamos
 * al interactuar con la pantalla
 */
@Override
public void update(float dt) {
 HandleInput(); //Mandamos a llamar este metodo
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Crear un `ImageButton` y asignar su posición y tamaño.
2. Añadir el `ImageButton` al `stage` utilizando `stage.add(button)`
3. El stage se debe actualizar `stage.act()`, y dibujar `stage.draw()` no tengo idea si lo estas haciendo por que en tu codigo no se ve.

```
public class MenuScreen implements Screen{
   private Stage stage;
   private Texture btnTextureUp;
   private Texture btnTextureDown;
   private Texture btnTextureChecked;
   private Button boton;

   @Override
   public void create(){
       btnTextureUp = new Texture("playUp.png");// aqui pones la textura que quieres cuando NO esta apretado el boton
       btnTextureDown = new Texture("playDown.png");// aqui pones la textura que quieres cuando se aprieta el boton
       btnTextureChecked = new Texture("playChecked.png");// aqui pones la textura que quieres cuando el botón esta "checked"

       SpriteDrawable up = new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(btnTextureUp));
       SpriteDrawable down = new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(btnTextureDown));
       SpriteDrawable checked = new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(btnTextureChecked));

       Button      boton = new Button(new Button.ButtonStyle(up,down,checked));
       boton.setSize(200,40);// aqui le ponemos un tamaño
       boton.setPosition(50,50);//aquí le asignamos la posición


       boton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                //AQUI PONES LO QUE QUIERAS QUE PASE CUANDO SE APRIETE EL BOTON
                gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
                dispose();
            }
        });


       stage = new Stage();

       stage.add(btninicial); // Añadimos el botón al stage

       Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); //Le decimos a libgdx que este stage va ser el responsable de manejar el input
   }

   @Override 
   public void render(){
       stage.act();
       stage.draw();
   }

   @Override 
   public void dispose(){
       stage.dispose();
       btnTextureUp.dispose();
       btnTextureDown.dispose();
       btnTextureChecked.dispose();
   }
}
```

`ImageButton` es un botón con dos imágenes, y se crea exactamente igual solo que tienes que poner un par de Texturas más y usar un `ImageButtonStyle` en lugar de un `ButtonStyle`